# Java: Can't find a good way to end this while loop

Tags: java

Context: i'm building a method that takes a string such as: 
"12+12" or "12/3+5*6-(12+1)"
and converts it to a string list like this:
[12, +, 12] or [12, /, 3, +, 5, *, 6, -, (, 12, +, 12, )]

I think you got the idea

I decided to go with a design wherr a for loop goes through each index of the original string and determines if the character of that index should be added to the list of if it should look for another digit after the digit before adding it. Problem came when i was writing a while loop which condition was that the next index (i+1) was either a digit or a . (dot). The problem is that when the last index in the string is a number, it looks for the character at an index that is higher than the length of the string. The only way that doesn't look ridiculous is to put it in a try/catch block as in this example: `String rawCalc = "12+12";

```
    while (i < rawCalc.length()) { // loop that goes through the string index by index

        String add = Character.toString(rawCalc.charAt(i)); // what is going to be added this iteration
        if (anyNumberPattern.matcher(Character.toString(rawCalc.charAt(i))).matches()) { // if the character at the
                                                                                            // current index is a
                                                                                            // digit
            try {
                while (anyNumberPattern.matcher(Character.toString(rawCalc.charAt(i + 1))).matches()
                        || Character.toString(rawCalc.charAt(i + 1)).equals(".")) { // check if the next index is
                                                                                    // also a digit or a point

                    add += Character.toString(rawCalc.charAt(i + 1)); // in that case, add that to the "add" string also

                    i++; // and go to the next character
                }
            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

            }
        }
        i++;

        refinedCalc.add(add); // add what "add" contains to the refinedCalc
    }

    System.out.println(refinedCalc);`
```

I'm new to programming, but i feel like it would be bad coding to use exceptions to stop while loops. Afterall they are called Exceptions which probably means they are meant to be used Ecxeptionally. So: who's got a good one-liner to stop my while loop from checking the last iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stopping a while loop can be easily achieved by simply add a break

```
while(true) {
   if(stop) 
     break;

   /*DO STUFF*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know this feature (pls no "READ THE DOCS", i have done but noone can remember every single word in there)

Comment: @BobMcCheatersen No problem. Just look at return, continue and break a 2nd time ;) They help a lot in such situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine several conditions:

```
while (i + 1 < rawCalc.length() && (anyNumberPattern.matcher(Character.toString(rawCalc.charAt(i + 1))).matches() || Character.toString(rawCalc.charAt(i + 1)).equals("."))) {
```

So if the first condition fails, the second one is not checked and no exception occurs.

Comment: I've come to realize this from other answer and concluded that i must have had a typo when i tried this before posting. My post should probably be deleted because of the fact that it is such a stupid question.

Comment: You should just accept an answer and upvote those which you liked

Answer (score 0):

You should add a length check in the inner `while loop` to avoid iteration going out of bounds.

```
 try {
                while (i < rawCalc.length()-1 &&  anyNumberPattern.matcher(Character.toString(rawCalc.charAt(i + 1))).matches()
                        || Character.toString(rawCalc.charAt(i + 1)).equals(".")) { // check if the next index is
                                                                                    // also a digit or a point

                    add += Character.toString(rawCalc.charAt(i + 1)); // in that case, add that to the "add" string also

                    i++; // and go to the next character
                }
            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

            }
```

Comment: I am convinced i tried this, but it still went out of bounds. I Understood this as that at runtime, even if the condition have "gone wrong", it still checks the rest and, by that, goes out of bounds.

Comment: I have edited the answer. The length check was ```i&lt;rawcalc.length``` and in the same condition, you are accessing char at ```i+1```, hence it would go out of bounds

Comment: If the outer loop is last element, inner loop should not check further elements

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `try-catch StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` then after the first `i++` add an `if` statement.

```
i++;
if (i > rawCalc.length()) break;
```

or maybe it's `i >= rawCalc.length()`.